# Materialized view with Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, materialized-views

I have the following line in a script and I don't understand what the "using" part is used for.
I couldn't find anything on google. Anybody familiar with that ?
Thanks a lot !!

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW "PVTRNDM"."DM_MVW_DAILY_CAL" 
 USING ("DM_MVW_DAILY_CAL", 
        (8, 'PLANVP.XXXX.INT', 1, 0, 0, "PVTRN", "DAILY_CAL", '2009-10-15 16:12:25', 8, 45073, '2009-10-15 16:12:25', '', 1, '0E', 6548400, 0, NULL), 
        2101313, 8, ('1950-01-01 12:00:00', 111, 0, 0, 6548400, 0, 2054, 2, NULL, NULL)) 
 REFRESH FORCE AS 
 select day_date, cal , sum(NVL(daily_du, 0)) AS daily_du FROM PVPROD.daily_cal GROUP BY day_date, cal ;
```

Comment: I am stumped. And even the documentation does't seem to cover this USING clause. Is this statement even valid?

Comment: Yes !
This one has a problem I'm trying to figure out but there are tons of others like these one in the script I have and all of them work perfectly !

Comment: Wish I could find out more.  Played with the syntax a little and it is valid.  Saw no documentation on it in a quick skim through relevant parts of SQL Reference, Data Warehousing, or Replication manuals.

Comment: BTW, which version of Oracle?

Comment: Where did the script originate?

Answer (score 1):

Well, this was interesting.  I took the code and plugged it into toad and made a few changes:

> CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW mv_jfhtesting
>   USING ("mv_jfhtesting",("hi","by"))
>   REFRESH FORCE AS  select "this","that"
>   from dual

This resulted in: ORA-12037 - Unknown Export Format
Which, when I looked it up was:

> Cause: An attempt was made to import a
>   materialized view exported by an
>   unknown export version (e.g., from a
>   newer release than the importing site)
>
> Action: Re-export the file using a
>   version of export known by the
>   importing site.

So, my guess is that this clause imports data from another MV.
(or even itself, maybe?)
Sorry I don't have time to play with this more

Comment: That looks good !!
Though I wonder how all these values are generated and what they mean ¿?

Comment: if I had to make a guess, its part of how the view was created in the first place.  Some of those values, if I had to guess, are more like defaults.  So, basically, someone set up an MV in some clever or interesting way with the USING clause, and some of those values it contains were specifically selected, and others were just generated by oracle (sort of like how you may just do "create table jfhtab (mycol1 varchar2(100))" but if you look at the script in TOAD or some such, you get all the storage parameters as well)

Answer (score 1):

Odd. Do you have the object in a database, and if so, what does DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL give you for it.
If that format of the SQL isn't there, I suspect someone has done an export of the schema and copied the SQL out of the DUMP file.

Comment: yes the code is coming from a dump file.
I'll try to see what DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL gives.

Comment: by the way, I'm not the db master at work. I'm a programmer. Just trying to help her out. For some reasons quite out of my league, she has to break an import.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've figured it out (or at least have a suggestion).
I did an export from a user that had a REFRESH ON DEMAND materialized view, then I tried importing that into a user that had CREATE TABLE, but not CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW privileges.

It created a table of that name, but errored out on the materialized view.
My guess is that when doing an export, it exports the data in the MV as a table. This odd syntax for CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW turns that table into an MV. I'd guess the dates are to do with when the MV was last refreshed on the source database (which may be relevant if there MV logs that can be applied for the next refresh).

Answer (score -1):

the USING is somekind of JOIN.

[Use "USING" for Joins](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Oracle/0140__Table-Joins/SimplifyingJoinswiththeUSINGKeyword.htm)

Comment: In a standard Select query, I would agree but while creating a view.. I don't know... Moreover why specifying all those values ?

Comment: The question is asking about a different usage of USING

Answer (score -1):

Their is a [USING INDEX](http://www.stanford.edu/dept/itss/docs/oracle/10g/server.101/b10759/statements_6002.htm) clause

Comment: Don't think so, the keyword INDEX would have to appear in the statement.

Comment: The question is asking about a different usage of USING (and also the link is broken).